# Does a Angel of Glory's Rise and a Fiend Hunter combo work like I think it does?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The scene I envision is that I have a graveyard full of humans, one of which is a [Fiend Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222007). I play [Angel of Glory's Rise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239993) and put all my humans from my graveyard and onto the battlefield, and when the [Fiend Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222007) enters the battlefield I target my [Angel of Glory's Rise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239993) to be exiled.

So, does that mean that when the [Fiend Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222007) who is holding my [Angel in Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239993) goes to the graveyard, the [Angel of Glory's Rise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=239993) comes onto the battlefield and thereby returns [Fiend Hunter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=222007) to the battlefield again, triggering his ability to exile a target creature anew?

If so, how does spells like [Cloudshift](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240006) effect that Fiend Hunter? If I used Cloudshift on the Fiend Hunter that was keeping my Angel of Glory's Rise in exile, would order of events look like this?

1. Cloudshift targets Fiend Hunter
2. Fiend hunter leaves battlefield - Angel of Glory's Rise returns from exile
3. Angel of Glory's Rise "enters the battlefield" ability triggers
4. Fiend hunter enters battlefield - Angel of Glory's Rise goes to exile

Or would using Cloudshift not trigger the Fiend Hunter's "leaves the battlefield" ability, exiling my Angel of Glory's Rise forever?

Finally, what if I had two or more [Champion of the Parish](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262861) that entered the battlefield from the graveyard due to the Angel of Glory's Rise's "enter battlefield" ability? Do they both come into play at the same time, so that both of them get a +1/+1 counter because they are both "another Human" to one another, or do they enter the battlefield one at a time?

Comment: My wife has a deck that abuses this exact mechanic.  Depending on your colors, if you run Blue, use a Dreamscape Artist to harrow, discarding humans and play your angel sooner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part of your combo does work. When the Fiend Hunter enters the battlefield, he can exile the Angel of Glory, and when the Fiend Hunter goes to the graveyard, he will already be there when the Angel returns, which allows you to repeat that combo indefinitely.

However, Cloudshift on Fiend Hunter is another matter. When the Hunter leaves the battlefield with the Angel exiled, he will indeed trigger the return of the Angel. However, the Hunter leaving and returning to the battlefield are all part of Cloudshift's resolution, so by the time the Hunter returns and you get to choose another creature to exile, the return of the Angel is still on the stack and is not yet back from its exile. You will have to choose another creature entirely, and if you don't happen to have a second Angel on the battlefield, the combo will end with the resolution of Cloudshift.

As for the Champion of the Parish question: The creatures enter the battlefield simultaneously. Creatures that enter the battlefield at the same time see each other enter the battlefield, so a Champion's triggered ability will trigger for each other Human entering the battlefield at the same time. For example, if you have 5 humans in the graveyard, and 2 of them are Champions, then each Champion's ability will trigger four times, so each would get a total of 4 counters.

Comment: Technically, the champion sees creatures that enter after -or at the same time- as him. They both see eachother enter and receive a counter.

Comment: So to have an emergency "get my fiend hunter out of the battlefield" ability I would need something like Faerie Imposter.

Comment: @Robobot Since it doesn't have flash, it's not much of emergency. Presumably you'd not have time to get it out in an emergency. You'd want like unsummon or saving grasp.

Answer (score 2):

> So, does that mean that when the Fiend Hunter who is holding my Angel in Glory goes to the graveyard, the Angel of Glory's Rise comes onto the battlefield and thereby returns Fiend Hunter to the battlefield again, triggering his ability to exile a target creature anew?

Yep, that's correct.

> If so, how does spells like Cloudshift effect that Fiend Hunter? If I used Cloudshift on the Fiend Hunter that was keeping my Angel of Glory's Rise in exile, would order of events look like this?
>
> 1. Cloudshift targets Fiend Hunter
> 2. Fiend hunter leaves battlefield - Angel of Glory's Rise returns from exile
> 3. Angel of Glory's Rise "enters the battlefield" ability triggers
> 4. Fiend hunter enters battlefield - Angel of Glory's Rise goes to exile
>
> Or would using Cloudshift not trigger the Fiend Hunter's "leaves the battlefield" ability, exiling my Angel of Glory's Rise forever?

Cloudshift does make the Fiend Hunter leave the battlefield, so the ability does trigger. But you've got the order entirely wrong, because you're ignoring the stack.

Here's what actually happens:

1. Cloudshift exiles Fiend Hunter ("leaves the battlefield" ability triggers and is queued to appear on the stack), then immediately returns Fiend Hunter to the battlefield ("enters the battlefield" ability triggers and is queued to appear on the stack).
2. "Queued" triggered abilities are placed on the stack, in APNAP order. Since you control both abilities, you get to choose which order they go on the stack. Suppose you put the "enters the battlefield" triggered ability on first and then the "leaves the battlefield" triggered ability on top of it.
3. Players have a chance to play instants and abilities
4. The top thing on the stack, the "leaves the battlefield" ability, resolves. This returns Angel of Glory's Rise to play. (If you had stacked the abilities in the other order, you would instead exile the creature targeted by the other ability at this point.)
5. The top thing on the stack, the "enters the battlefield" ability, resolves. This lets you exile the creature targeted by that ability. (If you had stacked the abilities in the other order, you would instead return Angel of Glory's Rise to play at this point.)

> Finally, what if I had two or more Champion of the Parish that entered the battlefield from the graveyard due to the Angel of Glory's Rise's "enter battlefield" ability? Do they both come into play at the same time, so that both of them get a +1/+1 counter because they are both "another Human" to one another, or do they enter the battlefield one at a time?

They enter at the same time, so they both see each other. Whenever an effect says "return all X to the battlefield" or "put all X somewhere" or something like that, you do it for all of them at the same time.

Comment: Targets are choosen for queued triggered abilities whenever those abilities are placed on the stack.  The other answer is correct that the Angel is not a valid target, because the Angel is still in exile waiting for Fiend Hunter's "leave the battlefield trigger" to return it.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that the ability was targeted. I'll edit.